# Centering a list within an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I will try and explain why I want to do what I am about to explain.
The content of the iframe is a simple list and is edited by people who get confused when they see html tags. They need to add a line to the top of the list so I want to avoid any tags.

I am able to display the list within an iframe.

I can center the iframe on the page.
(I know if I put html in the content it would be fine but I need to avoid this)

When displayed the content is not aligned centrally within the iframe (obviously).

Is there a way that I can do this 'easily' (not being an expert in HTML !)

I guess what I am looking for is  style="align-content=center";
as opposed to just aligning the position of the iframe itself which as I said, is no problem.

The best I can do  at the moment is to limit the width of the iframe so the content 'looks' as though it is central on the window, and therefore the content looks about central, but it isn't exactly what I need.
I saw someone said     but that made no difference to the content.

Any ideas please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<center>..</center>
```

tag where ever you want to make center alignment.

May This link will Help you..Try this..

click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Regds..

Comment: I cannot put the center tag into the iframe contents. This will only center the iframe itself.